# Add / remove GET parameter in URL with dynamic dropdown-Filter

Tags: php, jquery

I want to create 4 dynamic drop-down filters for a database query client side.
Since my `pdo-query` gets all the information from the URL, I need to manipulate this URL by adding, updating and removing these 4 parameters.
Right now, all the queries run perfectly when I change the URL by hand.
I guess using jQuery is the way to go, but I need a lot of help with this language.

The code for the dropdowns is following:

```
<select id="dynamic_select_company"> // On change the selected option is triggered
<?php 
  $countcompany = $pdo->prepare( $filterkomplex1 );
  $countcompany->execute(); ?>
<option value="Browse.php" selected>Choose Company...</option>

<?php while($showcompany = $countcompany->fetch()) {?>
<option 
<?php
  if ($_GET['Company'] == $showcompany['Company']) { ?> selected="true" <?php }; ?>
    value="<?php echo $furl ?>&Company=<?php echo $showcompany['Company']?>">  // i know this will append infinity GET_Parameters
<?php echo $showcompany['Company']?> (<?php echo $showcompany['anzahl']?>) </option>
<?php };?>
</select>

<button>Delete part of string where GET-Parameter is &Company=XYZ</button>
```

//And the remaining 3 in copy:

```
<select id="dynamic_select_line"> ...
<button>Delete part of string where GET-Parameter is &Line=XYZ</button>    
<select id="dynamic_select_group"> ...
<button>Delete part of string where GET-Parameter is &Group=XYZ</button>
<select id="dynamic_select_year">  ...  
<button>Delete part of string where GET-Parameter is &Year=XYZ</button>
```

Clearing off all filters will be no problem because I can simply make `href` without parameters...
I have no clue, what to do next.

Comment: Hi @Stefan Klein, can the 4 parameters (Company, Line, Group & Year) be combined ?

Comment: Yes, in any way! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to manipulate a url string as follow :

```php
$url  = 'Browse.php';
$data = array('Company' => 'W',
              'Line'    => 'X',
              'Group'   => 'Y',
              'Year'    => 'Z');

$queryString = http_build_query($data); // Company=W&Line=X&Group=Y&Year=Z
echo $url . '?' . $queryString;
```

Or you can use [http-build-url](http://php.net/manual/fa/function.http-build-url.php) but you'll need PECL pecl_http :

```php
echo http_build_url($url, $data, HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas Roehm, I did not know anything about that. This is much easier for me. I have built such a routine for each filter with individual adjustments and it works flawlessly. Thank you!